# Copy current php file classname with namespace?

Tags: vimscript, filetype-php

Currently I have this binding to copy current file name, path, or dir.

```
" Copy current buffer path relative to root of VIM session to system clipboard
nnoremap <Leader>yp :let @*=expand("%")<cr>:echo "Copied file path to clipboard"<cr>
" Copy current filename to system clipboard
nnoremap <Leader>yf :let @*=expand("%:t")<cr>:echo "Copied file name to clipboard"<cr>
" Copy current buffer path without filename to system clipboard
nnoremap <Leader>yd :let @*=expand("%:h")<cr>:echo "Copied file directory to clipboard"<cr>
```

I want to create binding to copy current php file class name with or without namespace.

Suppose I have php file like this:

```
<?php

namespace CRMFoundation\Infrastructures\Contracts;

interface PersistenceStorageRepositoryInterface
{ 
  ....
}
```

This would should give me `PersistenceStorageRepositoryInterface` as classname and `CRMFoundation\Infrastructures\Contracts\PersistenceStorageRepositoryInterface` with namespace.

```
<?php

namespace CRMFoundation\Infrastructures;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use CRMFoundation\Infrastructures\Traits\SyncHasManyTrait;

abstract class EloquentAbstract extends Model
{
  .....
}
```

This would should give me `EloquentAbstract` as classname and `CRMFoundation\Infrastructures\EloquentAbstract` with namespace.

```
<?php

namespace CRMFoundation\Domains\Company;

use CRMFoundation\Domains\Company\Contracts\CompanyRepositoryInterface;
use CRMFoundation\Infrastructures\Company\Contracts\PersistenceCompanyRepositoryInterface;
use CRMFoundation\Domains\Company\Contracts\CompanyInterface;
use CRMFoundation\Domains\RepositoryAbstract;

class CompanyRepository extends RepositoryAbstract implements CompanyRepositoryInterface
{
  ....
}
```

This would should give me `CompanyRepository` as classname and `CRMFoundation\Domains\Company\CompanyRepository` with namespace.

Let say I want to bind it to `<leader>yc` to get current class name and `<leader>ycn` to get current class name with namespace.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start, it's definitely not perfect but should gives you enough to increment on

```
function! GetNamespaceAndClassFn()
  " Save some registers
  let l:r_a = @a
  let l:r_b = @b

  " Start at the top of the file
  :0
  " Search for the first "namespace" occurence
  /namespace
  " Get the namespace string into the regsiter a
  normal! f l"ayt;

  " Search for the class definition
  /class
  " Get the class string into the regsiter b
  normal! f l"bye

  " Print the result
  echo @a . '\' . @b

  " Restore registers
  let @a = l:r_a
  let @b = l:r_b
endfunction

command! GetNamespaceAndClass call GetNamespaceAndClassFn()
```

I've commented the code, but feel free to ask if you want more info.